# MySQL error in loading CSV file data into table

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to load the contents of a CSV file into a table using the following MySQL commands on Windows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/TD_DI_026.csv'
INTO TABLE digitalTags
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

but this is giving me an error `The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`
I have already modified the my.ini file to include:

```
[mysql]
loose-local-infile=1
```

and the command

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

shows local_infile as turned ON.

I also tried by removing `Local` and setting `secure_file_priv = ""` in my.ini
But I am getting `Error Code: 29. File 'C:\Users\TD_DI_026.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an issue but security feature, you need explicitly enable for each database inclusion from local file:

```
mysql -u user -p --local-infile=1 YourDatabaseName
```

Make sure that `user` granted with `FILE` [privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file)

Also, don't place CSV file in `C:\Users\TD_DI_026.csv`, but used instead location:

```
C:\Users\Public\Download\TD_DI_026.csv
```

Add also this to `my.cnf/my.ini`:

```
[mysqld]
     local-infile = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error Code: 29. File 'C:\Users\TD_DI_026.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

MySQL cannot access the file in `C:\Users`, probably because it's owned by you.

Place it somewhere the MySQL Server can reach it, or explicitly grant access to some directory to the MySQL user.